# Select another object should fire `before:selection:cleared` event

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Here is my issue:
When you select an object and then click on a white space, `before:selection:cleared`event is correctly fired.

But when you select an object and then click on another object, this event is not fired (and so selection:cleared).

I guess it's not a bug, but shouldn't canvas fire selection:cleared event whenever it loses focus ?

The thing is that there is no other way (or I'm missing something) to get previous selected object if `before:selection:cleared` event is not fired when selecting another object, and that's a problem if you want to update selected object before he loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to store the currently selected object (Every time `object:selected` is fired).

When object:selected is fired the first time, your variable will be uninitialized, giving you the ability to know if it's the first selected object or not.

Comment: so you mean when object select i have to store that object in variable and when another object selected i have to do things on previously stored object?